# Read/Copy file from device using mtp connection on nodejs

Tags: node.js, macos, mtp

I use nodejs mtp module https://github.com/panuhorsmalahti/mtp to get files.

But I can't find a way to copy file to local disk. I use OSX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the posting the module! I was looking for an MTP node module

**Answer**

This is how to copy a file in node.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('doc.txt').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doc_copy.txt'));
```